# Magento 2 - custom admin menu > access denied

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, admin-controller

i have this controller
News\LatestNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News.php

and if i comment this

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{

   // return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('News_LatestNews::manage_news');

}
```

the page shows access denied, but If turn it on,

it shows this error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Boolean value is expected, supported values: array (
  0 => true,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 'true',
  3 => '1',
  4 => false,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 'false',
  7 => '0',
)
```

what is the problem?
how can i fix this?

## newBieInMagentohere

Comment: have you add `acl.xml`??/

Comment: have you tried var_dump($this->_authorization->isAllowed('News_LatestNews::manage_news')); to check the return type?

Comment: yes i already tried, and it returns true. I have acl.xml

Comment: In Admin Role u have permission for this module?

Answer (score 1):

Check for correct XML. Take a look for line breaks in values like

`<element>
\n   true
</element>`

In my case it was a copy'n'paste fail :D

Answer (score 0):

For people who came here from google - one of your config node has

```
 xsi:type="boolean"
```

But it's value is different, eg:

```
<item name="something" xsi:type="boolean">some_string_instead_boolean</item>
```